# How to hide half digits of phone number with star format in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, phone-number

I want to to hide last 7 digits of phone number like below image.

[image]

Comment: use [this](https://pub.dev/packages/masked_text) pub

Comment: I tried it But It's an editText and I only want to show number in hide format.

Comment: Add your code in question.

Comment: No need @VrushiPatel, I already resolved it :)

Comment: @ShrutiRamnandanSharma Okay good for you :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here, I resolved it by myself

```
String number="=+911234567890"

String newNumber=number;

String replaceCharAt(String oldString, int index, String newChar) {
       return oldString.substring(0, index) + newChar + oldString.substring(index + 1);
     }


   for(int i=6; i<number.length;i++){
         newNumber = replaceCharAt(newNumber, i, "*") ; 
         print("PHONE_NUMBER_LOOP:$newNumber");

    }

   print("FinalNumber:$newNumber");
```

Answer (score 5):

**I found a solution in flutter of dart**

> **For mail**

```
"example@gmail.com".replaceRange(
                                  0,
                                  "example@gmail.com"
                                          .indexOf("@") -
                                      3,
                                  "****")
```

It will show result like that- *******ple@gmail.com***

> **For Phone Number**

```
"01716422666".replaceRange(3, 8,"*****")
```

It will show result like that- 017*****666

> **Here is my own output**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

String mobileNumber="9191858591"

String afterHide=mobileNumber.replaceRange(2, 8, '******');

print(afterHide);

Result = 91*****91

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
void main() {
  String phoneNumber = "01783109748";

  String obscuredPhoneNumber = obscurePhoneNumber(phoneNumber);

  print("Original Phone Number: $phoneNumber");
  print("Obscured Phone Number: $obscuredPhoneNumber");
}

String obscurePhoneNumber(String phoneNumber) {
  if (phoneNumber.length == 11) {
    // Replace characters from index 5 to 8 with asterisks
    String obscuredPart = phoneNumber.substring(5, 9).replaceAll(RegExp(r'.'), '*');

    // Concatenate the parts
    return phoneNumber.substring(0, 5) + obscuredPart + phoneNumber.substring(9);
  } else {
    return phoneNumber; // Handle invalid phone numbers
  }
}
```